# stuck coding an app

Tags: ios, swift

The line of code I have now is

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent: UIEvent)
```

However I need it to be

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent: UIEvent)
```

But I get an error when I change it.

Comment: You can't change function signature of an override func!!!

Comment: override the (actual) `touchesBegan` function, cast the touches to a `UITouch` set, then pass the result to your second function (get rid of the `override` as there's no function with that signature).

Comment: Why do you want to change the set of `UITouch` objects to a set of `NSObject`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are overriding a function this means that the header of the function cannot be changed. However, if you want to change the function try writing the method without overriding. The problem with this is that if it is a method called by the controller of the object, then this method will not be called by default.